# Python SimpleHTTPServer able to register connection attempts?

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

A Python web server started with

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

will print on the console requests it has accepted. Can I get it to print requests that returned a connection refused to the client?

I am trying to debug why it refuses some requests from an Android client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If the client gets a `Connection refused`, this means that the connection request did not reach the server application. Therefore, the server application cannot possibly register these errors.

Check firewalls, routing, connectivity, and correctness of server address and port.